# ajax and jQuery: making sure the HTML page is rendered correctly

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Sorry if I will write imprecisions but I am fairly new to ajax and jQuery

I have this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
})
```

which contains two ajax GET;

The first obtains the HTML from a template and loads it into the current page.
The second loads the content from an XML file and loads it into the current page.

How can I make sure the page is correctly rendered having the guarantee that the second GET is fired after the first succeeded?
As it is, sometimes the page gets filled, sometimes not.
Thank you.

EDIT: that's the actual code I am using:

```
<script>
        var page;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "template.html",
                dataType : "html",
                success : function(html) {
                    $('body').load('template.html #generalBox');
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "GET",
                        url : "content.xml",
                        dataType : "xml",
                        success : function(xml) {
                            page = $(xml).find('aTag');
                            $('#content').html(page.text());
//other loadings
                        }
                    });

                }
            });

        });

    </script>
```

EDIT2:

resloved: the problem was in

```
                    $('body').load('template.html #generalBox');
```

which seemed to behave asynchronously from the rest of the code. I loaded the HTML using

```
success : function(html) {
                    var ndoc = document.createElement('html');
                    ndoc.innerHTML = html;
                    page = $('body', ndoc);
                    $('body').html(page.html());
//2nd get
```

and it works fine now.

Comment: clearly the second GET tries to modify some tags that are loaded by the first GET and would not exist in the document otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Call 2nd GET from the callback of the 1st GET after the DOM modification is done so the 2nd request will get executed when data from 1st GET are already loaded.

Very general example using `.ajax()`:

```
// 1st GET
$.ajax({
  // ...
  success: function(){
   // ...

   // 2nd GET
   $.ajax({
     // ...
   });
  }
});
```

**EDIT:**

`.load()` is loading content asynchronously, so you need to call the 2nd GET *after* the `.load()` finishes using optional callback - see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Try:

```
$.ajax({
  // ...
  success : function(html) {
    $('body').load('template.html #generalBox', function() {
      // 2nd GET should be executed in the callback of .load()
      $.ajax({
         // ...
      });
    });
   }
});
```

Comment: That's what I have done, but strangely enough, when I reload the page, sometimes it's rendered correctly and sometimes only the correct HTML is shown, without content. I think it may be a synchronization problem? By the way, I am calling       $('body').load('template.html #generalBox'); in the first GET before calling the nested one. EDIT see the code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
   url : "Your server url",
   data : "data to posted",
   type : "GET",
    success :function(){
       //call your second ajax here...
}
});

})
```